# Error while displaying COUNT(variable) in CrudRepository using SQL query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm facing some problem with displaying COUNT of a variable while querying a MySQL database. I have made a variable with annotation @Transient so that it's not included in the DB. But, I'm getting error while posting data in the same table in the DB, since while posting, there is no field count, count is only used to get COUNT(u_type). Is there any way with which I can display COUNT of a variable when I do a GET call (using SQL query) and no need to post it. TIA.

Class:

```
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class UserClickData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private String u_search_term;
    private String u_sysid;
    private String u_type;

    @Transient
    private long count;

    public UserClickData(String u_type, long Count) {       //, long count
        this.u_type = u_type;
        this.count=count;
    }
    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(long count) {
        this.count=count;
    }

    public int getSys_id() {
        return sys_id;
    }
    public void setSys_id(int sys_id) {
        this.sys_id = sys_id;
    }
    public String getU_search_term() {
        return u_search_term;
    }
    public void setU_search_term(String u_search_term) {
        this.u_search_term = u_search_term;
    }

    public String getU_type() {
        return u_type;
    }
    public void setU_type(String u_type) {
        this.u_type = u_type;
    }

}
```

Projection:

```
public interface UserClickProjection {
    String getU_type(); 
    long getCount();
}
```

DAO Code:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickData;
import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickProjection;
import com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserProjection;

public interface UserClickDataRepository extends CrudRepository<UserClickData, Integer> {
    public static final String FIND_QUERY = 
    "select new com.abc.datacollection.entity.UserClickData(user.u_type, COUNT(u_type)) from UserClickData user GROUP BY user.u_type ORDER BY COUNT(user.u_type) DESC";
    @Query(value = FIND_QUERY)
    //public List<UserProjection> getAllRequestResponseRecords();
     List<UserClickProjection> findAllProjectedBy();

}
```

Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody List<UserClickProjection> getAllUserClickDataRecords() {
        return userClickDataRepository.findAllProjectedBy();
    }
```

Comment: hi, guess you imported the wrong Transient class... should be `javax.persistence.Transient`

Comment: Please provide the stack trace for the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import javax.persistence.Transient instead of org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient